# Wordpress autoenroll bundle courses

Tags: wordpress

I have a PMP level that I would like to auto enroll to certain courses that are attached to that level. Attaching courses to a membership level is easy, but I cannot figure out how to auto enroll users that register at that level.

I know there is an option in LearnPress to auto enroll a user that registers for an individual course, but can this be done for a PMP level?

Any suggestions?